# Error using \boldsymbol

Tags: math-mode, brackets, boldsymbol

I am using `\boldsymbol` and am getting a strange error. Here is a MWE with all the packages I am importing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,hanging,amsthm,polynom,mathtools,verbatim,enumitem,fancyhdr,tikz,systeme,multicol,siunitx,titling,flexisym,hyperref,xparse, amstext, array,xfrac,datetime,advdate,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{f(x)}$ 
\end{document}
```

And here's the error message (assuming the test file is called 'main.tex'):

```
./main.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
\binrel@@ #1->\@symErr 
                       ?{\OrdSymbol {#1}}
l.5 $\boldsymbol{f(x)}
                      $
?
```

I can't figure out which package(s) are causing the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off topic: It's not necessary to string all package names onto a single line, and in fact it's a bad idea.  You repeat `amsthm`.  `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so it's not necessary to specify both.  `amstext` is included in `amsmath`, so that's not necessary.  And `hyperref` should almost always go last.

Comment: It's [`flexisym`](//ctan.org/pkg/flexisym). Do you need to use it?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying your example code to make it more minimal. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a direct sense, the error is caused by the fact that [flexisym](https://ctan.org/pkg/flexisym) is among the many packages that are loaded by your code. (@Werner has already pointed this out in a comment below your answer.) For sure, if one does *not* load the `flexisym` package, the error disappears.

In a broader sense, though, the error arises because your code violates some of `flexisym`'s implicit, but entirely reasonable assumptions about what constitutes good (or, at least, reasonable) coding practice. Specifically, it's the fact that by writing

```
$\boldsymbol{f(x)}$
```

you are telling LaTeX to render not only `f` and `x` in **bold**, but the symbols `(` and `)` as well. Sure enough, if you replace `\boldsymbol{f(x)}` with `$\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x})$`, the error vanishes -- even if `flexisym` is loaded.

Writing `\boldsymbol{f(x)}` really does constitute rather questionable coding practice from a aesthetic (typographic) point of view. Why? In fine math typography, rendering an item in **bold** not only creates a different *appearance* but also conveys a different *meaning*.

- Do you intend for bold parentheses to have a meaning that's different from that of ordinary, i.e., non-bold, parentheses? That would be unusual, to say the least. For sure, if it really *is* what you intend to say, you should make sure to state this explicitly, preferably somewhere near the beginning of the document, as otherwise many of your readers will probably miss that distinction.
- If you absolutely must bold-face not only `f` and `x` but the parentheses as well, you should load the `bm` (short for "bold math", I suppose) package and write $\bm{f(x)}$. `\bm` is easier to write than `\boldsymbol`, isn't it?
- However, do ask yourself if this is really what you want, or if you should be writing either `$\bm{f}(\bm{x})$` or  `$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$` instead. The former produces ***bold-italic*** output, and the latter produces **bold-upright** output, *while not bolding the parentheses*.

You may also want to clean up and provide some structure to the way you load LaTeX packages. I provide some suggestions in this regard in the code below. Do also ask yourself if your document really requires the loading many of these packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% First, some comments about your current approach to loading packages:
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'utf8' is the default nowadays
%\usepackage{%amsmath, % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
%    amsthm,amssymb,
%    hanging, % to simplify creating paragraphs with hanging indentation
%    %amsthm, % don't load packages twice (or three times, or ...)
%    polynom, % for typesetting polynomial long division
%    mathtools,
%    %verbatim, % since you load 'fancyhdr', I'd load 'fancyvrb' instead of 'verbatim'
%    enumitem,
%    fancyhdr,tikz,systeme,multicol,siunitx,
%    titling, % for more control over '\maketitle' and '\thanks' -- do you need it?
%    flexisym,
%    %hyperref, % this package should almost invariably be loaded *last*
%    xparse, 
%    %amstext, 
%    array,xfrac,
%    %datetime, % why don't you load the newer and more capable 'datetime2' package?
%    advdate, % this package was last updated in 1996 -- do you need it??
%    mathrsfs}

%% Suggestion: Take a more structured approach to loading packages.
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,flexisym,xfrac} % 'math-y' packages
\usepackage{bm} % <-- new, for '\bm' macro
\usepackage{polynom,systeme,siunitx} % 'sort-of math-y' packages
\usepackage{hanging,fancyvrb,fancyhdr,multicol,enumitem,titling,datetime2}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref} % observe that this package is now loaded *last*

\begin{document}
% This causes an error:
% $\boldsymbol{f(x)}$
% The following examples work fine:
$\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x})$, $\bm{f(x)}$, $\bm{f}(\bm{x})$, $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
$\bm{x}$ & $0$ & $2$ \\ 
\hline 
$\bm{f(x)}$ & $1$ & $3$ \\ 
%\hline 
$\bm{f(x)}$ & $-2$ & $2$ \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```